# How to Disable generating sourcemap with expo build:web

Tags: react-native, expo, google-chrome-devtools

I tried with putting

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

in .env file,  running command

```
set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" &&  expo build:web
```

and

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false expo build:web"
```

in scripts inside package.json
nothing works. Devtools show my everything.

How can I protect my source from being exposed with expo:build?

Answer (score 3):

Working with this for a while...

You can just build your web app like

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false expo build:web
```

Or edit your package.json as

```
"scripts": {
  "custom-web-build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false expo build:web",
  "...": "..."
}
```

Then

```
yarn custom-web-build
```

Note that you might have to clean your browser cookies or use a private window to see the changes.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even in private mode. Any update on this ?

Comment: GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npx expo export:web this command not working for me

Answer (score 0):

After testing with @expo/webpack-config@18.1.0
the following works fine

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false npx expo export:web -c
```